# How is the creation of entangled two-photon states such as $|00\rangle\pm|11\rangle$ compatible with the conservation of angular momentum?

Tags: entanglement

Quoting, "Spin is the simplest example — two photons would either be (+1 and -1) or (-1 and +1), two electrons would either be (+½ and -½) or (-½ and +½) — and you don’t know which is which until you measure it"
Source: https://medium.com/starts-with-a-bang/ask-ethan-whats-so-spooky-about-quantum-entanglement-e62c35ba339d

Question: The above states of photon polarization: (+1 and -1) relates to entangled state of 01+10 and is understandable for conservation of ang. momentum.

How is the state 00+11 realized in terms of polarization. Does not having two photons with (+1 and +1) violate conservation of ang. momentum?

Comment: are you asking how a two-photon entangled polarization state can be generated in practice?

Comment: yes ,and especially in the state of 00+11.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/119429/58382, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion, https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/262210/58382

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're already happy with producing $|01\rangle+|10\rangle$, it's enough to see how another state such as $|00\rangle+|11\rangle$ can be made out of the first one. This just requires the introduction of a bit of kit known as a half wave plate. It pretty much just swaps 0 and 1 and vice-versa, so you apply it on just one of the photons.

Comment: This is definitely correct, but it provokes the follow-up question "What happens to angular momentum conservation at the wave plate?" Then you get into classic questions like https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94416/291677 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80535/291677